# Intermittent DNS failures

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, amazon-route53, dig, tld

We have intermittent DNS failures. Upon troubleshooting we found from our server, (where the domain is pointed to)  gives connection timeout when queried against few TLD ns.
Ex: dig domain @tldns (Connection timed out;; no servers can be reached)

but dig domain @tldns +trace works. Will this connection timeouts cause intermittent failures or what is difference between +trace & notrace?

NOTE: The TLD registar were able to resolve the same TLD nameservers from their servers.

Comment: @Hema Can you add more details

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot reveal the domain name. But the domain is failing to resolve the origin name intermittently and recovering back in 2 minutes. We are suspecting it as an issue with Top Level domain nameservers (.tw) . When we do dig mydomain @ tldnameserver it gives connection timeouts. But, dig mydomain @ tldnameservers +trace is resolved (gives nameservers of my domain as an answer).  Ram, could you please let me know in which area I could add more information

Comment: Is your firewall allowing port 53 **UDP** through?

Comment: I think you have purchased your domain from one of your hosting provider (Like Godaddy) and your server might in AWS..

Comment: You are facing problem from hosting site to server, Am I right

Comment: "Unfortunately i cannot reveal the domain name."  Then do not expect quick relevant replies. Domains are public, they are published to be queried by anyone...

Comment: Ours is a huge platform and has multiple sites hosted in route53 aws. No other domain had this problem except this. @ Ram you are right we have purchased domain name from external provider and currently hosting in AWS. All the nameservers of the domain are correctly mapped to aws nameservers

Comment: @BandariHema We regularly get people coming here who believe it's all set up correctly, but it turns out not to be the case. You may be in that scenario; we're limited in our ability to help you diagnose if you keep it a secret.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ..Domain :msdconnect.tw

Answer (score 2):

Three things you have to be careful

1. Check whether your **Name servers are pointing to Route 53.**
2. Add only the required **records in your Route 53 DNS** server.

[image: Check here for Route 53 Records]

3. Also check whether your **server is accessible via IP Address** that you had given in your DNS Record